# Android SQLCipher and DB from assets folder

Tags: android, sqlcipher

At the moment, my sqlite db file is **NOT** encrypted and it's copied from the `assets` folder to the application `data/data/mypackage/databases` folder.

Now I want to add the [SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/) libraries to my project and start using them.
Can I encrypt the db file and copy it to `assets` and use the same key inside the application?
Is it possible to encrypt the database on Windows? What I need to do?

Comment: The goal of SQLCipher is to help the *user* protect *their* data from others. You appear to be attempting to prevent the user from accessing their data. This will not work. "Can I encrypt the db file and copy it to assets and use the same key inside the application?" -- yes, but you are wasting everyone's time, because anyone who wants to can simply get the key out of your app and decrypt the database. If you do not want the user to access this data, do not put the data on the user's device.

Comment: humm I see your point... So it's not possible, right? So using the scenario that I integrate SQLCipher on my application, I should let the user choose the password, is that it? So I'm not able to use a db from assets, I will need to build the db with statements?

Comment: "So it's not possible, right?" -- I am not sure what "it" is. "is that it?" -- yes. "So I'm not able to use a db from assets, I will need to build the db with statements?" -- you could ship an unencrypted database in assets, *then* encrypt it with the user's chosen password using SQLCipher.

Answer (score -2):

i think we should do like that

```
SQLiteDatabase normalDB = null;
SQLiteDatabase cryptedDB = null;
normalDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, "", null,
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
    | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

cryptedDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
    encrypteddbPath, Constants.CRYPT_KEY, null);

Cursor cursor;

cursor = normalDB.query(TABLE_CITY,
new String[] { FIELD_CITY_CODE, FIELD_NAME1,
    FIELD_NAME2, FIELD_NAME3 }, null, null, null,
    null, null);
int i = cursor.getCount();
while (i > 0) {
    ContentValues newLabelValues = new ContentValues();

newLabelValues.put(FIELD_CITY_CODE, cursor.getString(0));
        newLabelValues.put(FIELD_NAME1, cursor.getString(1));
        newLabelValues.put(FIELD_NAME2, cursor.getString(2));
        newLabelValues.put(FIELD_NAME3, cursor.getString(3));
        cryptedDB.insert(TABLE_CITY, null, newLabelValues);

cursor.moveToNext();
}
```